# Python - Stop Scrolling Message on SenseHat

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

So i'm making this dice on a Raspberry pi SenseHat and I want the scrolling message to stop if a "shake" has been detected and then display the dice.
I have tried using sys.exit on the thread t1, but it exits the whole program. Does it have something to do with the way i'm making threads, cuz both threads have the same id for some reason. Or do you think there is an easier way to do this?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import threading as th
import random
import time
import sys

sense = SenseHat()

sense.clear()

def show_message_nw(message) :
    global sense
    sense.show_message(message)

t1 = th.Thread
t2 = th.Thread


def message_new_thread(message):

    t1(target=show_message_nw, args=(message,)).start()
    print(th.get_ident())

message_new_thread("Shake to Roll Dice")


#define color pixels                   
r = [255, 0, 0] # red pixel
g = [0, 128, 0] # green pixel
b = [0, 0, 0] # no color pixel



# Set one to six die pattern                   
one = [
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
]

two = [
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,g,g,b,b,
b,b,b,b,g,g,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
]

three = [
r,r,b,b,b,b,b,b,
r,r,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,r,r,
b,b,b,b,b,b,r,r,
]

four = [
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
]

five = [
r,r,b,b,b,b,r,r,
r,r,b,b,b,b,r,r,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,r,r,b,b,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
r,r,b,b,b,b,r,r,
r,r,b,b,b,b,r,r,
]

six = [
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
b,g,g,b,b,g,g,b,
]

# define a die function from pattern one to six
def roll_die():
    r = random.randint(1,6) 
    if r == 1:
           sense.set_pixels(one)
    elif r == 2:
           sense.set_pixels(two)
    elif r == 3:
           sense.set_pixels(three)
    elif r == 4:
           sense.set_pixels(four)
    elif r == 5:
           sense.set_pixels(five)
    elif r == 6:
           sense.set_pixels(six)

#Use accelerometer to read the motion from senseHat
def main():
    while True:
        stop_threads = True
        x, y, z = sense.get_accelerometer_raw().values()

        x = abs(x)                
        y = abs(y)
        z = abs(z)

        if x > 1.4 or y > 1.4 or z > 1.4:
            t1(target = sys.exit(),).run()
            print(th.get_ident())
            roll_die()
            t = 0.5            
            time.sleep(t)

t2(target = main()).start()
```